# Laravel Collection filter a collection by values from another collection

Tags: php, laravel

I'm in the process of building a custom Collection class but I'm having some issues on filtering data.

I have a collection of financial data, ($collection) that looks like this:

```
App\CustomCollection {
    #items: array [
        0 => {
            +"financials": [
                0 => {
                    +"data_tag": {
                        +"tag": "revenue"
                    }
                    +"value": 1200
                }
            ]
            +"fundamental": {
                +"fiscal_year": 2018
                +"fiscal_period": "FY"
                +"start_date": "2018-01-01"
                +"end_date": "2018-12-31"
            }
            +"company": {#336
                +"id": "com_TEST1"
            }
        }
        1 => {
            +"financials": [
                0 => {
                    +"data_tag": {
                        +"tag": "revenue"
                    }
                    +"value": 300
                }
            ]
            +"fundamental": {
                +"fiscal_year": 2018
                +"fiscal_period": "Q1"
                +"end_date": "2018-03-31"
            }
            +"company": {#336
                +"name": "Test Company Inc"
            }
        }
        2 => {
            +"financials": [
                0 => {
                    +"data_tag": {
                        +"tag": "revenue"
                    }
                    +"value": 300
                }
            ]
            +"fundamental": {
                +"fiscal_year": 2018
                +"fiscal_period": "Q2"
                +"end_date": "2018-06-30"
            }
            +"company": {#336
                +"name": "Test Company Inc"
            }
        }

        ... etc to Q4
    ]
}
```

I can successfully return my Fiscal Years with the following:

`$fiscalYears = $collection->where('fundamental.fiscal_period', 'FY');`

Returns:

```
App\CustomCollection {
    #items: array [
        0 => {
            +"financials": [
                0 => {
                    +"data_tag": {
                        +"tag": "revenue"
                    }
                    +"value": 1200
                }
            ]
            +"fundamental": {
                +"fiscal_year": 2018
                +"fiscal_period": "FY"
                +"start_date": "2018-01-01"
                +"end_date": "2018-12-31"
            }
            +"company": {#336
                +"id": "com_TEST1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I can also return just the quarters by doing:

`$fiscalYears = $collection->where('fundamental.fiscal_period', '!=', 'FY');`

```
App\CustomCollection {
    #items: array [
        0 => {
            +"financials": [
                0 => {
                    +"data_tag": {
                        +"tag": "revenue"
                    }
                    +"value": 300
                }
            ]
            +"fundamental": {
                +"fiscal_year": 2018
                +"fiscal_period": "Q1"
                +"end_date": "2018-03-31"
            }
            +"company": {#336
                +"name": "Test Company Inc"
            }
        }
        1 => {
            +"financials": [
                0 => {
                    +"data_tag": {
                        +"tag": "revenue"
                    }
                    +"value": 300
                }
            ]
            +"fundamental": {
                +"fiscal_year": 2018
                +"fiscal_period": "Q2"
                +"end_date": "2018-06-30"
            }
            +"company": {#336
                +"name": "Test Company Inc"
            }
        }

        ... etc to Q4
    ]
}
```

Everything is great here and works fine, but now what I am trying to accomplish is to return only quarters that match specific values in $fiscalYears.

Here is what I am using now:

```
public function quartersByFiscalYears($fiscalYears)
    {
        $quarters =  [];
        foreach ($fiscalYears as $fiscalYear) {
            $quarters[] = $this->quarters()->where('company', $fiscalYear->company)
                ->where('fundamental.end_date', '>=', $fiscalYear->fundamental->start_date)
                ->where('fundamental.end_date', '<', $fiscalYear->fundamental->end_date)
                ->values('financials');
        }

        return $quarters;
    }
```

**The most important part of the code above is that it returns only quarters where the $quarter end_date >= the $fiscalYear start_date and where the $quarter end_date < the $fiscalYear end_date.**

This works, but it is by far the slowest "filter" in my collection. I have a feeling that I am thinking about this all wrong, although I'm not sure. It seems like looping over the entire collection every time $fiscalYears iterates is a bad idea. Can this be done in a faster/more efficient way? Or is foreach pretty common in this scenario?

Comment: I can't see the relations between your models, but have you looked at eager loading? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: These are just collections built from raw files, not using eloquent or models

Comment: You should give an example of the result you expect

Comment: I don't see how the last code result differs from the second one (`$collection->where('fundamental.fiscal_period', '!=', 'FY')`)

Comment: @VincentMimoun-Prat '!= FY' returns all quarters and the other example is filtered with `quarters.end_date >= fiscal_year.start_date` and `quarters.end_date < fiscal_year.end_date`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each "group" in your resulting data contains the quarters for a particular company in a given year. You can use eloquent methods to get this done MUCH faster than looping over the quarters. I tested this with 40k records. Looping took ~45 secs, but this takes less than a second.

```php
$quarters = $collection->where('fundamental.fiscal_period', '!=', 'FY');

// use `groupBy()` to organize the quarters into the right chunks
$grouped = $quarters->groupBy(function($item) {
    // concatenate the company name and fiscal year to create the "group" name
    return $item->company->name.'_'.$item->fundamental->fiscal_year;
});

// use `$fiscalYears` with `map()` and `flip()` to create a collection 
// with the same key structure as $grouped
$filter = $fiscalYears->map(function($item) {
    return $item->company->name.'_'.$item->fundamental->fiscal_year;
})->flip();

// filter the collection with `intersectByKeys()`
$result = $grouped->intersectByKeys($filter);

// If you want, replace the keys with numeric indices and convert to array
$result = $result->values()->toArray();
```

Just be careful about which eloquent methods you use. If you use `flatten()`, that method uses recursive loops under the hood, so it will still be slow.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work. It is imperative that i generate the final results by filtering `quarters.end_date >= fiscal_year.start_date` and `quarters.end_date < fiscal_year.end_date` like I do in the last code block of my question. I will clean up my question a bit as I do notice it is kind of hard to understand.